# Bridge the last and next non-NA value with intermediate values that grow evenly

Tags: r, data.table, na, locf

What would be a good way to fill the missing NAs in a dataframe column with intermediate values that grow gradually from the last non-NA value to the next non-NA value?

Here is an example: for the column cost, I would like to obtain the column cost_esti where the cost increase by $31 each year between 2014 and 2016, bridging the last known cost of $595 to the next known cost of $720

[image]

The code I came up with is lengthy. Is there an elegant way to do the same?

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(year=2000:2018,
                  cost = c(100,120,NA,200,220,NA,NA,300,350,470,500,NA,NA,595,NA,NA,NA,720,800))

data[,cost_nas:=as.numeric(is.na(cost))]

## consecutive nas so far for each row:
data[, consecutive_nas_so_far := seq_len(.N), by=rleid(cost_nas)]
data[cost_nas==0,consecutive_nas_so_far:=0]

# total number of consecutive nas in the sequence
data[,total_number_of_consec_nas:=ifelse(consecutive_nas_so_far>0&shift(consecutive_nas_so_far,1,type = "lead")==0,consecutive_nas_so_far,NA)]
data[cost_nas==0,total_number_of_consec_nas:=0]
data[,total_number_of_consec_nas:=zoo::na.locf(total_number_of_consec_nas,fromLast=T)]

#get last and next known values for cost:
data[,cost_previous:=zoo::na.locf(cost)]
data[,cost_following:=zoo::na.locf(cost,fromLast=T)]

# apply the formula to calculate the gradual increase from cost_previous to cost_following
data[,cost_esti:=round(consecutive_nas_so_far*(cost_following-cost_previous)/(total_number_of_consec_nas+1)+cost_previous,0)]
data[is.na(cost_esti),cost_esti:=cost]
```

Comment: Two suggestions: `approx` and `lm`/`predict` will both support your logic of replacing missing values with interpolations.

Comment: Maybe rowid(cumsum(!is.na(x)))-1L

Comment: oh wow. approx did exactly what I needed in 1 line of code. data[,cost_esti:=(approx(cost,n=.N))$y]. genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `re-write` data.table operations using `zoo::na.locf` and `data.table::rleid`. Add 2 columns, one each for `lastNonNA` and `nextNonNA` using `na.locf`. `rleid` will provide you distinct group for continuous `NA`. Now you can write logic to fill `NA` using `linear` between `lastNonNA` and `nextNonNA`.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
#Data
data = data.table(year=2000:2018,
       cost = c(100,120,NA,200,220,NA,NA,300,350,470,500,NA,NA,595,NA,NA,NA,720,800))

data[,':='(lastNonNA = na.locf(cost, fromLast = FALSE), 
nextNonNA = na.locf(cost, fromLast = TRUE), Group_NA = rleid(is.na(cost)))][
  ,':='(IDX = 1:.N), by=Group_NA][
  ,':='(cost = ifelse(is.na(cost), lastNonNA + IDX*((nextNonNA - lastNonNA)/(.N+1)),cost)), 
    by=Group_NA][,.(year, cost)]

#    year     cost
# 1: 2000 100.0000
# 2: 2001 120.0000
# 3: 2002 160.0000   #Filled
# 4: 2003 200.0000
# 5: 2004 220.0000
# 6: 2005 246.6667  #Filled 
# 7: 2006 273.3333  #Filled
# 8: 2007 300.0000
# 9: 2008 350.0000
# 10: 2009 470.0000
# 11: 2010 500.0000
# 12: 2011 531.6667 #Filled
# 13: 2012 563.3333 #Filled
# 14: 2013 595.0000
# 15: 2014 626.2500 #Filled 
# 16: 2015 657.5000 #Filled
# 17: 2016 688.7500 #Filled
# 18: 2017 720.0000
# 19: 2018 800.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for in the question is a linear interpolation.
It can be obtained quite easily in R for your data with NAs.

In this case the solution would be:

```
library("imputeTS")
na_interpolation(data, option = "linear")
```

You could also use option = "spline" or "stine" then the increase wouldn't necessarily strictly linear.